# Perl regex testing blank or expression

Tags: regex, perl

Why is this expression returning true for character `1` or `V` (and others)?
How could I rewrite it so that it would return true only when it's blank or a character from `a-z`?

```
~((^$)||(^[a-z]$))~
```

Comment: as tested on http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is in the middle:

```
||
```

That means:

```
OR the empty string OR
```

And the empty string can be between any character.  Or no characters.  Basically, you're saying "Match anything."

To do an OR with a regex, only use a single pipe.

You can simplify this to:

```
/^[a-z]?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Empty string or one character in the range a-z would be:

```
/^[a-z]?$/
```

Remember that `?` means "0 or 1 of this" -- so the regexp translates to "0 or 1 character between a and z inclusive".

Rewriting it to use an `|` for "or" (note how much more ugly it is, so this is just an academic exercise at this point) you could do:

```
# nothing, or one character in a-z
/^(?:|[a-z])$/
```

Comment: Your last expression should match any string that has a start -- ie: everything.

Comment: Your second one is still a bit off :)  `perl -e "my $foo = '#!@#'; print $foo =~ /^|[a-z]$/ ? 'matches' : 'not match'"` prints `matches` (the `|` goes across the entire regex.)

Comment: @Robert, @cHao: hmm you're right, I got the binding order mixed up. time for parentheses! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of why you should prefer `\z` rather than `$` to mean "end of string". The pattern `/^[a-z]?$/` will happily match a string consisting of a single newline.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $s = "\n";

if ( $s =~ /^[a-z]?$/ ) {
    print "string consisting of a single newline matched\n";
}

unless ( $s =~ /^[a-z]?\z/ ) {
    print "string consisting of a single newline did not match\n";
}
```

Comment: @Kinopiko Thank you for the compliment. It's just gotchas like this stick in my mind once I have been bitten.

Answer (score 1):

It matches because the expression contains `||`.  The regex 'or' operator is a single `|`; two of them means 'or nothing or', and every string will match an empty expression with no anchors.

Either way, your regex seems a bit complex...how about `/^([a-z]?)$/`?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you change it to something like this:

```
^([a-z]?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\A(\p{Lower})?\z/
```